# Funtion created ggplot to ggplot object

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to create a `ggplot` object from a function generated plot. I am using a function for creating dual y-axis plot in `ggplot` and it works, but I cannot convert it to a `ggplot` object with class `gg` and `ggplot` like other `ggplot`objects.

Like if we have two plots like these:

```
p1 <- qplot(wt, mpg, data=mtcars)
p2 <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(price, colour = cut)) + geom_density()
```

Now I combined these two using these codes and produced the third plot:

```
p3 <- grid.arrange(p1,p2,ncol=2)
```

It produced the plot, but I cannot recall the `p3` plot later, means it didn't render as `ggplot` as it did for `p1` or `p2`.

I don't want to export as pdf or image file right now. My idea is to use the `p3` plot later and combine with other `ggplots`.

Comment: please share some codes, how your tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `grid::grid.draw` to print the `gtable` objects created by `grid.arrange`. 
If you wish to suppress the output when combining `p1` and `p2`, use `arrangeGrob` instead of `grid.arrange`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)

p1 <- qplot(wt, mpg, data=mtcars)
p2 <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(price, colour = cut)) + geom_density()

p3 <- arrangeGrob(p1,p2,ncol=2)
grid.draw(p3)
```

[image]

```
p4 <- arrangeGrob(p3, p1, nrow=2)
grid.draw(p4)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sumedh. It was really helpful.